# Can we generate junit test report in excel format using ant script

Tags: ant, junit

I have number of testcases for my application.
I am running all these test cases with one test suite.
And I generated ant script to build them for automation.
Everything goes smooth up to this.
But when I run this build.xml file, generated test results are representing in HTML file format.
Is there any way to write my test results into an excel file?
After every test case execution, excel file should update with Test case name and result.
Actually, I am not that far along in my experience with testing as I am a developer.
So, could anyone make a way to go with,what I need.

Comment: By the way excel is program will operate in GUI mode. Can you elaborate on the excel file updating the test case name and result. This part is not clear to me.

Comment: Say I have 10 test cases,TC1,TC2...TC10.These test cases are running with TestSiute.So after finishing each case, result should be written into excel(with 2 columns, name and result) with
result and name.Hope you got,what I am trying to get.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite possible. You need to create a stylesheet as in [Convert an XML file into an Excel spreadsheet with this technique](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-an-xml-file-into-an-excel-spreadsheet-with-this-technique/6163451) that you will pass to the [ant junitreport](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junitreport.html) task. The generated file extension should be ".xml". You have to explicitly open with excel. Make sure you customize the stylesheet to match your office version.

You can see the excel generated XML by creating a simple excel sheet and select File -> Save As. Choose the file type as xml.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Suresh.But the link, which you have shared is not useful for me.It isn't describing from XML to excel conversation.
I want to write Test result into Excel file after finishing each Test Case.And it should stop rest of test cases execution, if any test case happen to fail.

Comment: The link I sent to you details how to convert an XML file to a excel spreadsheet. I did not understand why you mentioned that the link did not have the conversion. You asked for a solution on have to accomplish this. Any junit task generates XML test report which you pass as input to the junitreport task. The junitreport task in turn will generate the excel sheet as in the link. You can control the Test execution by setting the appropriate flags to the junit task.